# What is a Duplivert, or a Dupliframe, internally?

Tags: linked-data, data-blocks, dupli-groups

I've been using Dupliverts, and Dupliframes without fully understanding their internal representation in Blender. (i.e. which Data Blocks are linked,and  which are copied, how parenting is related to all this)

I would like to know what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.. 'Make Duplicates Real' is actually doing - what the difference is between Duplicates, and the instances that result from the execution of that command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll put here the data structure diagram for reference:

[image]

*The material can be linked to Data (default) or to Object*

The *Object* is just a container for the *Object Data* within, which is a separate datablock inside Blender, that can be used by any number of same type *Objects*.  Similar like a Material can have multiple users.

---

There are different ways you can make copies:

- **Duplicate Object** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> - duplicates the object and by default also the mesh. What is duplicated and what is instantiated can be set in *User Preferences* under *Editing*:

  [image]
- **Duplicate Linked** <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> - duplicates the object, but links the rest (like leaving all checkboxes from point above unchecked). In case of mesh object makes a mesh instance - shares only 1 mesh between them - object data is not duplicated
- **Duplivets, duplifaces, dupliframes:**

  - tells Blender to use own object data (verts, faces, animation data at all frames) as transforms for copies of parented object(s)
  - the copies are instances of the parented object(s), nothing is duplicated, not even the object
- **Dupligroups**

  - same as before, but whole group of objects is instantiated
  - makes only 1 copy using own's object transformation, doesn't make much sense to use enything else than *Empty Object*.
- **Particle/Hair systems:**

  - transforms are taken from particle data
- **Linked object/group:**

  - same as with *Dupligroup*, but links from another .blend file.

---

When you *Make Duplicates Real* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, only the first relation in the chain changes from instances to real duplicates. You can now set different modifiers, materials (if you link them to object), constraints, etc. for these now real objects, but they still keep just one mesh linked between them - exactly same like a mesh instance.

To turn them into full duplicates use *Make Single User* <kbd>U</kbd> > Object & Data: this creates a mesh duplicate for each object, turning them into full copies (ctrl-d) effectively and you can now edit each copy's mesh data independently.

Comment: Do dupligroups make 1 copy inside the target .blend or is it constantly reading the source .blend?

Comment: The structure is much more flexible than I thought it was. I don't remember 3DS or XSI being able to pick and choose data-blocks to copy or link in this way, beyongd 'instances' and 'copies' Perhaps they could, but I didn't know enough. Anyway, to me, Blender makes a lot more sense if I've got the gist of what's going on under the bonnet.

Comment: @Way2Close when you open .blend file it loads into RAM and everything happens there until you save it to disc.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it true duplicates get their own object data block, whereas a group instance is reading the original's datablock. In blender the group instance is simply attached to an empty so you can move and rotate it and such, it is then locked from edit mode because it is a reference. Basically an instance takes up no extra memory but can't be edited.

Comment: I _think_ you've described to me the difference between copies and instances ... that instances share mesh data, and copies don't. But Duplis seem to be different again. They behave like instances..( if you modify one's mesh, the others are modified too)  And the 'Make Duplicates Real' command results in _actual_  instances.  So there's something they were before executing that command, and I'm interested in what that something is.

Comment: Surely it's just a collection of linked instances parented to an 'EMPTY'? make_real would just create a separate instance for each object in the group.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. I've been looking at it again.. there is no empty,  so that's not exactly it. Maybe it's just the terminology that's confusing me.. I guess I'm trying to understand this from a programmer's point of view.

Comment: If you select an instanced group and use bpy.context.active_object.type it prints 'EMPTY', confirmed if you go into the properties window and go to the object data tab you can even adjust the axis size of the placeholder empty.

Comment: ... I'll go back and look harder,.... is that the same, with a dupliframe or duplivert?

Comment: Way2Close.. hope you don't mind I accepted Jaroslav's answer. that is what I was looking for.  Thanks for your attention to the question.