# Using different materials on each instance of an object with a mirror modifier

Tags: modeling, materials, modifiers, mirror

Is it possible to have each instance of an object with a mirror modifier using different material? An example would be a door modeled only on one half, but where each side would be in a different color:

[image]

Or is applying the modifier permanently the price to pay in order to be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to go around the mirror modifier and create 2 copies of the door each with different material, but with the same mesh they share between each other:

1. Get rid of the mirror modifier.
2. For each material slot set it to be linked to *Object*:

   [image]
3. Make an instance of the door with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. This will duplicate the object, but link the same mesh between them. More on this can be found here:

   [What is a Duplivert, or a Dupliframe, internally?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109297/what-is-a-duplivert-or-a-dupliframe-internally)
4. Scale one object in the axis you want to `-1` to mirror. Arrange them accordingly.
5. Assign different materials to the material slot(s).

   [image]

Comment: Exactly the solution I needed, the linked question's answer is also very useful.