# Mirroring objects

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have created one tree. Leaves have one origin point and the body has another. Later I parent them.

I keep copying them by alt+d. Suddenly I want to Mirror it to avoid  monotony. When I applied Mirror modifier I see nothing happened. Later I realized in this tree I have two origin points, one for leaves another for the body.

How can I mirror such complex thing which has two origin points?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest that for the ones you want to mirror, take a copy of the original (leaves and tree) and join them (Ctrl+J) rather than parent them. This will leave a single origin point for the bunch and will be much easier to work with when mirroring, etc.... Granted, this will mean you now have 2 objects which you are instancing from (at least for the trees), but I don't think it will make a huge difference performance-wise.

Comment: I started blender two days ago only. I am following  a tutorial  where the tutor does this. Mirroring them is my Curiosity. In that course the guy just alt+d the tress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Mirror* modifier is not used the way you want to use it here, it's generally used to symmetrize a topology, not to duplicate an object in a scene. Also the *Mirror* modifier will use the origin of the object as center of the symmetry, so if you wanted to create a symmetrical tree you needed to move the mesh away from the origin (or move the origin).

Also, do you have a reason why you don't join the trunk to the leaves <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>? As Christopher says it would make sense to have only one object.

Instead of using the *Mirror* modifier you could link duplicate the object with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> then press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd> and you'll have a mirrored version of your object and the meshes are still linked.

You can also use *Collection Instances* instead of *Linked Duplications*, see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127487/multiple-instances-of-one-object-mesh/127507#127507).

Also some rotations on Z and you won't realise that it's the same tree.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137257/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-mirroring-objects).