# Cloner Object (like in C4D) in Blender

Tags: objects, groups

**Solution**

The *Array Modifier* is basically equivalent to the Mograph Cloner in Cinema 4D. I was a bit confused since there is also a Mography Array in Cinema 4D which I would not need for this case.

To stack objects vertically you have to:

- Go to the *Modifiers Tab*
- Choose *Array*
- Uncheck *Relative Offset*
- Check *Constant Offset*
- Change the Z value

[image]

**Problem**

I would like to duplicate an object and stack it. The current scenario is that I have a business card and I would like to stack the business cards. Here is a screenshot of the project, it is quite simple:

[image]

In Cinema 4D (I have used it before Blender) there was a function called "MoGraph Cloner Object" you can see the function of it in this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/2rWnJzf8O0w?t=43s

Of course I could duplicate it and just stack it but this does not feel like a good solution since I have to change EVERY duplicated object instead of just one.

I have tried to google it but I was not successful.  Thanks for any help that is provided.

Kind regards,

Fabian Lins

Comment: After watching that video, it acts like the Array modifier in Blender? Tried using the Array modifier?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have not tried the Array Modifier in Blender yet. I have heard of it a bit but did not think it was what I need since there is also an Array Modifier in Cinema 4D. It basically just makes copies of the object aligned as a circle. youtube.com/watch?v=WlT_uquqDqM This video shows what I mean. But I will look up the Array Modifier in Blender. Kind regards, Fabian Lins

Comment: An array would definitely do the job. What you've maybe missed, is that you can use an Empty to drive the transformations (it acts like the "P.X, S.X, R.H...."). Create an Empty at the same LRS of your object. In the Array parameters, uncheck Relative,check Object and select the Empty ; then, move/rotate/scale the Empty.

Comment: That definitely did the trick. I had to choose constant offset instead of relative offset and to stack the plane/ the card I had to change the Z value.
Now I need to like how I can add some randomness to the copies but this is a different question. Kind regards, Fabian Lins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are after instancing. How this works in Blender is explained here:

[What is a Duplivert, or a Dupliframe, internally?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109297/what-is-a-duplivert-or-a-dupliframe-internally)

You can also use the [Array modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html) to make copies, then deform them with another modifier (lattice for example).

The equivalent of MoGraph node system in Blender is the [Animation Nodes addon](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: I have been successful with the Array modifier. Thanks for your answer. Have not looked up the other two points though. But to be fair stacking a plane vertically is not too complex. Kind regards, Fabian Lins